# Как сделать поиск двух одинаковых чисел подряд в массиве? и почему код неправильный?

Tags: javascript

Почему этот код всегда выводит 'нет'?

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9];
var flag = false;
for (var i = 1; i < arr.lenght; i++) {
  if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
    flag = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (flag === true) {
  alert('да');
} else {
  alert('нет');
}
```

Comment: length .........

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9];
let flag = false;
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] === arr[i - 1]) {
    flag = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (flag) {
  alert('да');
} else {
  alert('нет');
}
```